# WPTerm ssh connection not working

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm running wordpress on a docker container. I've logged in via the admin console and installed the `WPTerm` plugin. When starting the WPTerm and using `ssh` with the following arguments

```
./ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -v -T -i ./id_rsa root@172.10.10.2
```

I get the error

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
Authenticated to 172.10.10.2 ([172.10.10.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
shell request failed on channel 0
```

I have tried different settings for WPTerm  `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system`, `passthru` and `popen` but all of them throw the same error.

How can I get the ssh client to open a shell?